# Why does my function just blink and brings me back to the home page?

Tags: javascript, function, call

All that happens is it blinks for like a second my button I want to make visible but it doesn't print hello world and it doesn't stay there just blinks.

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="Document.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function All() {
      var name = document.getElementById("search");
      visible()
    }

    function visible() {
      document.getElementById("back").style.visibility = "visible";
      David()
    }

    function David() {
      if (name === "David") {
        Document.write(
          "Hello World"
        );
      }
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body onload=" invisible()">
  <center>
    <h2>Enter A Last Name</h2>
    <form>
      <input style="width: 300px;position: relative;top: 100px;" id="search" type="textbox" name="search">
      <input style="position: relative;top: 100px;" type="submit" value="search" name="button" onClick="All()">
      <input style="position: relative; right: 900px;" id="back" type="submit" value="Back" name="button" onClick="">
    </form>
  </center>
</body>

</html>
```

Also the `onload=" invisible()"` is just calling a function in `<script src="Document.js"></script>` but I'm not having any problems with that all it does is make the button invisible when the page loads but here's the code for it anyway.

```
function invisible()
{
    document.getElementById("back").style.visibility="hidden";
}
```

Comment: don't use `Document.write` after page loads... will overwrite existing content...best to not use it at all

Answer (score 0):

You are using a form submit for it and the default event for form submit is to go to the action specified on the form. If there is no action on the form, it just refreshes the page. If you want to keep the form submit, you have to stop the default event with return false;

```
function All (){
var name = document.getElementById("search");
visible();
return false;
}
```

That should fix your problem.

You could also use a "button" tag or just an "a" tag.

Answer (score 0):

Changing Submit to a button made my object "back" visible how ever it didn't remove the search bar and the search button and it also didn't print hello world but thanks for the help

Comment: Did you try to set the return to false instead of changing the submit to a button?